# Get diff on rerender in React

Tags: dom, reactjs

Is there a way to get the diff that React is getting of the DOM/Components? I can imagine trying to store changes as they happen so the user can 'undo' the changes [and am personally interested in the availability of the diff that is underlying the rerender (perhaps it would have the components that have changed?)].

EDIT: The undo feature was just an example. I am just interested in whether the above is possible to extract from React, since it is supposedly doing a diff of new and old tree.

Comment: *"I'm trying to store changes as they happen so the user can 'undo' the changes."* Keep a snapshot of the state of your app / component instead. Then "undo" is simply loading the previous state. It's really not clear to me why you would want a diff of the **DOM**.

Comment: The app/component itself is tree-like - it would just be convenient to have access to the diff, since I want to keep track of it anyway, perhaps store the information for other purposes. I'll need to create a separate diff otherwise, but if I could tap in and get that information; could potentially be useful.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm trying to store changes as they happen so the user can 'undo' the changes

My proposition how to accomplish this:

React render result should be based only on states. If you give two times identical state, then DOM should be identical. Possibly child components should be stateless.

`componentWillUpdate` method is run after changes in props and states.

You can copy and save state after any state change.

And if user 'undo' changes then set old saved state as current state.

And DOM should be identical to previous state.

Comment: Agreed, with React your goal is to not have to alter the DOM or worry about the DOM state, instead you deal with the state of your data and the DOM is rendered deterministically from that.

Comment: @krzysztof-sztompka While I agree with this, my question is asking from the point of view if you do care about the virtual DOM. I'm imagining the diff would consist of components and not actual DOM elements.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but in my answer I tried to help you with this problem in React way. Working with react we should leave virtual dom for react. I don't know if this is even possible to manipulate virtual dom.

Comment: Thank you; completely understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) in combination with [redux-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo) if you want undo/redo functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: *Probably*, **but you shouldn't do it like that**

Imagine if you had the diff of the DOM, then you would have to parse the DOM and figure out which dom changes mapped to different parts of props and state.

Thats messy.

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  onChange: function(newData){
    currentState = _.clone(this.state.currentState)
    previousChanges = this.state.previousChanges.concat([currentState])

    this.setState({
      currentState: newData,
      previousChanges: previousChanges
    })
  },

  undo: function(){
    previousChanges = _.clone(this.state.previousChanges)
    currentState = previousChanges.pop() // removes last item and returns it

    this.setState({
      currentState: currentState,
      previousChanges: previousChanges
    })      
  },
  render: function(){
    <div>
      <SomeAwesomeThing 
        currentState={this.state.currentState} 
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onUndo={this.undo}
      />
    </div>
  }
})
```

You basically have to keep a pointer to the current data, and to a list of changes, where each change can easily be reverted to.